# Best Practice for Reacting to Params Changes with Vue Router

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

When using Vue Router with routes like `/foo/:val` you have to add a watcher to [react for parameter changes](https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/dynamic-matching.html#reacting-to-params-changes). That results in somewhat annoying duplicate code in all views that have parameters in the URL.

This could look like the following example:

```
export default {
    // [...]
    created() {
        doSomething.call(this);
    },
    watch: {
        '$route' () {
            doSomething.call(this);
        }
    },
}

function doSomething() {
    // e.g. request API, assign view properties, ...
}
```

Is there any other way to overcome that? Can the handlers for `created` and `$route` changes be combined? Can the reuse of the component be disabled so that the watcher would not be necessary at all? I am using Vue 2, but this might be interesting for Vue 1, too.

Comment: Hmm. The v1 router had a canReuse but I don't see that in v2. Interesting.

Comment: @ceejayoz You are right, it was there but [has been removed](https://vuejs.org/guide/migration-vue-router.html#canReuse-false-removed).

Comment: Well, ! Starring this question.

Comment: Hi , please see my answer for vue3

Answer (score 56, accepted):

One possible answer that I just found thanks to a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/issues/474#issuecomment-254252898) is the following.

It is possible to use the [`key` attribute](https://vuejs.org/guide/list.html#key) that is also used for `v-for` to let Vue track changes in the view. For that to work, you have to add the attribute to the `router-view` element:

```
<router-view :key="$route.fullPath"></router-view>
```

After you add this to the view, you do not need to watch the `$route` anymore. Instead, Vue.js will create a completely new instance of the component and also call the `created` callback.

However, this is an all-or-nothing solution. It seems to work well on the small application that I am currently developing. But it might have effects on performance in another application. If you really want to disable the reuse of the view for some routes only, you can have a look at setting the `key`'s value [based on the route](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/issues/474#issuecomment-258139659). But I don't really like that approach.

Comment: this works thank you, however I have child components inside of these routed components and they don't get preserved. i see they're emitting mounted events each time i switch between the two routed components who are mounted separately and only once. Is there a way to keep their child components alive as well? <keep-alive> collapses all children onto one, even when I use a key.

Comment: Thanks, it still works perfectly with Vue3

Answer (score 1):

vue3 and script setup:

```
watch(route, () => { fetch()})
```

in import:

```
import { watch } from 'vue';
import { useRoute } from 'vue-router';
const route = useRoute()
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this variant without `:key` prop on `router-view` component.

routes.js:

```
     {
        path: 'url/:levels(.*)',
        name: ROUTES.ANY_LEVEL,
        props: true,
        component: (): PromiseVue => import('./View.vue'),
      },
```

view.vue

```
<template>
    <MyComponent :config="config" />
</template>

---*****----

<script>
data: () => ({ config: {} }),
methods: {
    onConfigurationChanged(route) {
      const { params } = route

      if (params && params.levels) {
        this.config = // some logic
      } else {
        this.config = null
      }
    },
  },
  beforeRouteUpdate(to, from, next) {
    this.onConfigurationChanged(to)
    next()
  },
}
</script>
```

Inside the component, I use the config as a property. In my case, reactivity is preserved and the component is updated automatically from parameter changes inside the same URL.
Works on Vue 2