# Vuejs: Event on route change

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

On my main page I have dropdowns that show `v-show=show` by clicking on the link `@click = "show=!show"` and I want to set `show=false` when I change the route. Please advise me on how to realize this thing.

Comment: For vue3 please see my answer.

Answer (score 484, accepted):

Setup a [watcher](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers) on the `$route` in your component like this:

```
watch:{
    $route (to, from){
        this.show = false;
    }
}
```

This observes for route changes and when changed ,sets `show` to false

Comment: And use `$route: function(to, from) {` if you want to support older browsers, and aren't using babel.

Comment: but how can I react immediately to route params or query params if the component is  getting instantiated / initialised at first? Would I do it in created() or mounted() or beforeRouteUpdate lifecycle hook or where?

Comment: Why would anyone not use Babel @PaulLeBeau?

Comment: This helped me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40404787/best-practice-for-reacting-to-params-changes-with-vue-router

<router-view :key="$route.fullPath"></router-view>

Comment: Excelent, i needed this to update my toolbar between sections

Comment: @PeterChaula hah, I was about to add the same comment)

Answer (score 61):

If you are using v2.2.0 then there is one more option available to detect changes in $routes.

To react to params changes in the same component, you can watch the $route object:

```
const User = {
  template: '...',
  watch: {
    '$route' (to, from) {
      // react to route changes...
    }
  }
}
```

Or, use the beforeRouteUpdate guard introduced in 2.2:

```
const User = {
  template: '...',
  beforeRouteUpdate (to, from, next) {
    // react to route changes...
    // don't forget to call next()
  }
}
```

Reference: https://router.vuejs.org/en/essentials/dynamic-matching.html

Comment: A note: `beforeRouteUpdate` works only on the view that declares the method and not on any child component

Comment: The watch (1st code block) works also in **Vue3**

Answer (score 54):

Just in case anyone is looking for how to do it in Typescript, here is the solution:

```js
@Watch('$route', { immediate: true, deep: true })
onUrlChange(newVal: Route) {
    // Some action
}
```

And yes as mentioned by @Coops below, please do not forget to include :

```js
import { Watch } from 'vue-property-decorator';
```

**Edit:**
Alcalyn made a very good point of using Route type instead of using any:

```js
import { Watch } from 'vue-property-decorator';    
import { Route } from 'vue-router';
```

Comment: Don't forget to include in the import:     `import { Prop, Watch } from "vue-property-decorator";`

Comment: I took me hours to finally realize that, any documentation out there?

Comment: Similar doc I can find: https://router.vuejs.org/api/#the-route-object Also instead of using the `any` type, you may want to use the interface `Route` from `import { Route } from 'vue-router';`

Answer (score 23):

Watcher with the deep option didn't work for me.

Instead, I use **updated()** lifecycle hook which gets executed everytime the component's data changes.
Just use it like you do with **mounted()**.

```js
mounted() {
   /* to be executed when mounted */
},
updated() {
   console.log(this.$route)
}
```

For your reference, visit the [documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#updated).

Answer (score 15):

Using Vue3 and the composition API you can do

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
import { watch } from "vue";
import { useRoute } from "vue-router";

const route = useRoute();

// do a `console.log(route)` to see route attributes (fullPath, hash, params, path...)
watch(
  () => route.fullPath,
  async () => {
    console.log("route fullPath updated", route.fullPath);
  }
);
</script>
```

References and examples here: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/composition-api.html#vue-router-and-the-composition-api

Answer (score 10):

```
import {  useRouter } from "vue-router";

const router = useRouter();

router.afterEach((to, from) => { });
```

Answer (score 7):

**UPDATE**

As stated by @CHANist, `router.listen` no longer works, I don't know from which version it stopped working, but the good news (as also stated by @CHANist) is we can use:

```js
this.$router.history.listen((newLocation) => {console.log(newLocation);})
```

**OLD Response**

The above responses are the better, but just for completeness, when you are in a component you can access the history object inside the VueRouter with:
this.$router.history.
That means we can listen to changes with:

```js
this.$router.listen((newLocation) => {console.log(newLocation);})
```

I think this is mainly useful when used along with this.$router.currentRoute.path
You can check what I am talking about placing a `debugger`

instruction in your code and begin playing with the Chrome DevTools Console.

Comment: downvoted because I get error this.$router.listen is not a function

Comment: @AngJobsonGithub Hi, from where are you calling this, this.$router will only be accessible on a Vue component, are you calling it from somewhere else? such as fetch()?

Comment: I think the call was inside a vue file,  this.$router is available but not the `listen` function.

Comment: @AngJobsonGithub It has to be called from within a Vue component, "this" should be a Vue Component and the project should be using VueRouter

Comment: The code mentioned above seems does not work in Vue 2.6.11. The code need to change to the following `this.$router.history.listen((newLocation) =>{console.log(newLocation);})` in order to make it work. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Another solution for typescript user:

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Component from "vue-class-component";

@Component({
  beforeRouteLeave(to, from, next) {
    // incase if you want to access `this`
    // const self = this as any;
    next();
  }
})

export default class ComponentName extends Vue {}
```

Comment: Thanks! this is what I'm looking for. Route leave event for a specific component.

Comment: Thnl's this what I want, but no I want also check if navigation window will closed or if url was changed manually, can you help me ?

Answer (score 3):

I hope you doing well,
in **vue3** and **script setup** this work is too easy:

```
watch(route, () => { fetch()})
```

be careful you must import before

```
import { watch } from 'vue';
import { useRoute } from 'vue-router';
```

and define use route :

```
const route = useRoute()
```

Answer (score 1):

using **Vue Router** is an alternative way, use the **beforeRouteLeave** after methods in your component like this:

```
<template>
   <button @click="ShowMethod">DisplayButton</button>
</template>
<script>
  data() {
    return { show: true };
   },
   methods: {
   ShowMethod() {
   this.show = false;
    }
   },
   beforeRouteLeave(to, from, next) {
   this.show = false;
   next();
 }
</script>
```

according to VueJs documentation, it's called **Navigation Guards** check the link below:

[Navigation Guards](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#global-before-guards)

> The leave guard is usually used to prevent the user from accidentally
> leaving the route with unsaved edits. The navigation can be canceled
> by calling

In-Component Guards:

> beforeRouteEnter
>
> beforeRouteUpdate
>
> beforeRouteLeave

```
  beforeRouteLeave(to, from, next) {
// called when the route that renders this component is about to
// be navigated away from.
// has access to `this` component instance.
 }
```

look at the below link for more information:

[In-Component Guards](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#in-component-guards)

Answer (score 1):

Using the Vue.js option API, this is how you can watch for changes on anything (like `$route.path`). In this piece of code, when the component is mounted, it will watch for changes in the path:

```
export default{
   mounted(){
      this.$watch( ()=> this.$route.path,(to, from)=> {
         console.log('route path has changed from ' +from+' to '+to )
      })   
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `beforeEach` event which allows any function to occur when the route is changing, just don't forget to call the `next()` function to proceed next operation, basically it has the same job as the backend expressJS middleWare.

```js
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  store.commit('setError', null); //in this example on each route I'm removing the error noted from the old route
  document.title = `${to.meta.title} | HartWork`; //on each route I'm adding a prefix to document title.
  next(); //calling next to proceed next functions and operations
})
```