# How update a VUE component changing URL param in current page

Tags: vue.js, router

In my vue SPA I have a simple router like this:

```
 {path: '/page/:userId', name: 'user', component: user},
```

Which means an url like http://xxx.xxx/user/1 shows the component user having the content about user 1.

In case on the same page I have some link as

```
<vue-link :to="{name:'user', params={userId:3}}">
```

The router update **only** the URL but the content page (because it assumes the page is the same where I'm at)

My user content loads data using the url params in data  and in watch too

**data**

> userId: this.$route.params.userId || 1,

**watch**

```
  watch: {

        userId: function () {
            return this.$route.params.userId || 1;
        },
```

How to fix it without using router-view?

Thanks for any suggestion

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vuejs: Event on route change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46402809/vuejs-event-on-route-change)

Comment: yes we are talking about router but this is a different case, imho.

Comment: Explain us how ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I correctly get your problem which is that you are not able to track your route change. You need to watch the `route` change, whenever your route changed on a same component it should do something.

```
watch: {
    $route() {
        this.updatePage(this.$route.params.userId)
    }
},
methods: {
   updatePage(param) {
     // call api / do something
   }
}
```

Comment: Yes! You got it! I love vue and you! I used it into the parent component and it works like a charm!