# bootstrap-vue navbar doesn't uncollapse in mobile when a button is clicked on the navbar

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-vue

I've used bootstrap-vue to implement a navbar on my vue.js app. When the  elements are clicked the navbar uncollapses as expected. I've replaced one of the navitem with a  so I can make it stand out and give it it's own CSS, but when the button is clicked the navigation works correctly but menu stays collapsed. Is there a way to force it to uncollapse?

```
<template>
  <b-navbar toggleable="lg" type="light">
    <b-navbar-brand to="/"> <img src="static/img/logo.svg" width="220px"></b-navbar-brand>
    <b-navbar-toggle target="nav-collapse"></b-navbar-toggle>
    <b-collapse id="nav-collapse" is-nav>
      <b-navbar-nav>
        <b-nav-item to="/about-us">About Us</b-nav-item>
        <b-nav-item to="/landlords">Landlords</b-nav-item>
        <b-nav-item to="#">Tenants</b-nav-item>
        <b-button class=" " to="/search">Valuation</b-button>
      </b-navbar-nav>
    </b-collapse>
  </b-navbar>
</template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Styling the native `b-nav-item`

The easiest solution would be to stick with `b-nav-item` and apply your classes to the item using either the `class` attribute, to add a class to the `li`, or the `link-classes` prop to add it to the rendered `a` tag.

This way you let Bootstrap-Vue handle the collapse close, making it more future proof in case something changes in the future.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app'
})
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap@4.5.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.15.0/dist/bootstrap-vue.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.11/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.15.0/dist/bootstrap-vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <b-navbar toggleable="lg" type="light">
    <b-navbar-brand to="#">
      LOGO
    </b-navbar-brand>
    <b-navbar-toggle target="nav-collapse"></b-navbar-toggle>
    <b-collapse id="nav-collapse" is-nav>
      <b-navbar-nav>
        <b-nav-item to="#">About Us</b-nav-item>
        <b-nav-item to="#">Landlords</b-nav-item>
        <b-nav-item to="#">Tenants</b-nav-item>
        <b-nav-item to="#" link-classes="btn btn-primary text-white">
          Valuation
        </b-nav-item>
      </b-navbar-nav>
    </b-collapse>
  </b-navbar>
</div>
```

#### Closing the collapse *manually*

Another option is to close the collapse by adding a click handler to your custom element in the navbar, that closes the collapse if open.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      isCollapseOpen: false
    }
  },
  methods: {
    closeNavCollapse() {
      if(this.isCollapseOpen) {
        this.$root.$emit('bv::toggle::collapse', 'nav-collapse')
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap@4.5.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.15.0/dist/bootstrap-vue.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.11/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bootstrap-vue@2.15.0/dist/bootstrap-vue.js"></script>


<div id="app">
  <b-navbar toggleable="lg" type="light">
    <b-navbar-brand to="/">LOGO</b-navbar-brand>
    <b-navbar-toggle target="nav-collapse"></b-navbar-toggle>
    <b-collapse v-model="isCollapseOpen"  id="nav-collapse" is-nav>
      <b-navbar-nav>
        <b-nav-item to="#">About Us</b-nav-item>
        <b-nav-item to="#">Landlords</b-nav-item>
        <b-nav-item to="#">Tenants</b-nav-item>
        <b-button to="#" variant="primary" @click="closeNavCollapse">
          Valuation
        </b-button>
      </b-navbar-nav>
    </b-collapse>
  </b-navbar>
</div>
```

#### Using a watcher to automatically detect route changes.

Alternatively you can use a [watcher](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46403063/8397974) and detect when the route changes and manually close the collapse.

Comment: perfect! I tried hard to apply classes but missed the link-classes prop. I've replaced the button with this and it works. Thanks!