# Vuejs : Rendering components conditionally based on route

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Some of the components needs to be hidden for particular Routes. I was able to achieve that using watcher for route change found from this SO question - [Vuejs: Event on route change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46402809/vuejs-event-on-route-change). I don't  want to show header and sidebar in customizePage ( route - /customize ). But there is a problem when I do a hard reload from that particular page. That doesn't execute the watch and hence the it fails. The solution I found was having it also in mounted(), so that it executes also on reload.

But having the same function in mounted and watcher looks weird. Is there a better way to do it ?

```
<template>
    <div>
        <TrialBanner v-if="$store.state.website.is_trial"/>
        <div class="page-body-wrapper" :class="{ 'p-0' : isCustomizePage}">
            <Sidebar :key="$store.state.user.is_admin" v-if="!isCustomizePage"/>
            <div class="main-panel" :class="{ 'm-0 w-100' : isCustomizePage}">
                <Header v-if="!isCustomizePage"/>
                <div class="content-wrapper" :class="{ 'p-0' : isCustomizePage}">
                    <router-view :key="$store.state.websiteId"></router-view>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>


mounted() {
  if(this.$route.path == '/customize') {
     this.isCustomizePage = true;
  } else {
     this.isCustomizePage = false;
  }
},
watch: {
  $route (to, from){
     if(this.$route.path == '/customize') {
       this.isCustomizePage = true;
     } else {
       this.isCustomizePage = false;
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: You should consider using vue-router hooks instead of the watcher: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#in-component-guards.

Also, if you don't find any other solution, it would be cleaner to factorise the duplicated code into one single method :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Easy fix:**
Use an immediate watcher

```
watch: {
  $route: {
     immediate: true,
     handler(to, from) {
         if(this.$route.path == '/customize') {
           this.isCustomizePage = true;
         } else {
            this.isCustomizePage = false;
         }
     }
  }
}
```

**More complex but more extensible fix:**
Use "layout" components.

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/reverent-chaum-g75jq)

General idea is to create "Layout" components, use the `meta` tag on routes to define the layouts for each route, and then use a dynamic component in App.vue to tell the app which layout to use.

App.vue

```
<template>
  <div id="app">    
    <component :is="layout">
      <router-view></router-view>
    </component>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  name: "App",
  computed: {
    layout() {
      return this.$route.meta.layout || 'default-layout';
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Default layout component

```
<template>
    <div>
        <TrialBanner v-if="$store.state.website.is_trial"/>
        <div class="page-body-wrapper" >
            <Sidebar :key="$store.state.user.is_admin" />
            <div class="main-panel">
                <Header />
                <div class="content-wrapper">
                    <slot></slot>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: 'DefaultLayout',
};
</script>
```

Sample customize page layout

```
<template>
    <div>
        <TrialBanner v-if="$store.state.website.is_trial"/>
        <div class="page-body-wrapper" class="p-0">
            <div class="main-panel" class="m-0 w-100">
                <div class="content-wrapper" class="p-0">
                    <slot></slot>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  name: 'CustomizeLayout',
};
</script>
```

Main.js: register layout components as global components

```
import DefaultLayout from '@/layouts/DefaultLayout.vue';
import CustomizeLayout from '@/layouts/CustomizeLayout.vue';

Vue.component('default-layout', DefaultLayout);
Vue.component('customize-layout', CustomizeLayout);
```

Router.js: routes define the layouts for each route

```
const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'home',
    component: HomeView,    
  },
  {
    path: '/customize',
    name: 'customize',
    component: CustomizeView,
    meta: {
      layout: 'customize-layout'
    }
  }
];
```

The `<slot></slot>` in each layout component is where the View will render.  You can also have multiple [named slots](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html#Named-Slots) and [named views](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/named-views.html) if you want to render different `components` in areas per layout.