# Vue beforeRouteEnter wait for child component to finish request

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router, beforerouteenter

I have a Vue app where I am using beforeRouteEnter to load data, and avoid a "flash of unloaded content". On some pages, this is easy:

```
 async beforeRouteEnter(to, from, next) {
    const newestPosts = await getNewestPosts();
    next(vm => vm.posts = newestPosts);
}
```

But it's not clear how to get this working when the data lives in child components of the page.

Lets say I have a structure like this

```
<search-page>
  <posts-list :query="$params.query">
  </posts-list>
</search-page>
```

Where `<posts-list>` has all the logic for querying for posts. It's used to build the "related posts" box, or the main search page - or shown on a user's profile page. It's nifty to have it encapsulate the fetching and rendering logic.

I wish I could do something in my `beforeRouteEnter` like:

```
 async beforeRouteEnter(to, from, next) {
    await this.$refs.postsList.finishedPromise;
    next();
}
```

But instead it looks like I'll have to put all the fetching logic in the beforeRouteEnter function. But that means I have to do that for potentially every page - removing some of the utility of the `<post-list>` component. Is that the only valid solution? I can't quite figure out if vuex would be a solution here. I understand how vuex helps with state (EG "sidebar.open") but could it help with managing search results, in a way that lets me leave the fetching logic in `<post-list>`?

Comment: Load data in the parent and pass it to children via props

Answer (score 0):

If the data needed to fetch the posts is contained in `$params.query`, one approach is to [watch](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Watchers) your `query` prop inside the `posts-list` component. When a change is seen, `posts-list` can determine whether it represents cause for fetching and perform that asynchronously after setting some kind of loading placeholder, like a nifty [skeleton loader](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/skeleton-loaders/#skeleton-loaders), which is a nice visual compromise for empty state.

I would avoid trying to interfere with routing changes, and rather think of how to [watch for them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46402809/vuejs-event-on-route-change) with reactive logic in the component that "needs to know".