# How to call a function before component is destroyed

Tags: vuejs2, vue-router

I am navigating to a route which have a component: Diagnostic

The route looks like

> localhost:8080/sav/:id/diagnostic

Whenever the route is visited I send a post request to the backend in order to **lock** the object which match the :id

I want to send another post request (execute a function) whenever the user navigate somewhere else in order to **unlock** the object

I used Vue JS lifecycle hooks with BeforeUnmount, unmounted, destroyed :

```
unmounted() {
  this.unlockObject()
}
```

I also tried to use watch to execute the function on route changes.

But none worked

I am not sure if the component is even unmounted when I navigate somewhere else in my app.

How to call my function when user navigate somewhere else?

I am using vue2 with vue router

Comment: this one was already answered [check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46402809/vuejs-event-on-route-change)

Comment: not working as when an user click somewhere else the component get destroyed and so get the watcher

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my own question

```
beforeDestroy () {
  this.unlockObject()
}
```

did the trick...

The function name is case sensitive