# How to extend the onClick handler behaviour for a `router-link` in vue3 router

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I have a `<router-link />` that I want to use to navigate to another page in a Vue 3 application, but I also want to run another function when this link is clicked.

Right now I have to use an extra `<span />` element to wrap the `<router-link />` and add the `@click` attribute there to rely on event bubbling. Adding the `@click` handler on `<router-link />` causes the router link not to work and the browser thinks it is just a normal anchor href.

```
    <span @click="handleClose(imageId)">
      <router-link
        :to="{name: 'image', params: {'imageId': imageId}}"
        class="permalink">
        Permalink
      </router-link>
    </span>
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: Maybe this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46403063/1844007 ?

Answer (score 5):

To avoid potential weird concurrency bugs (the view change could happen before your method being called, method which would then be attached to an unmounted component), I would do a programmatic navigation in your method:

```js
<template>
  <button type="button" @click="handleClose(imageId)">
    Permalink
  </button>
</template>

<script>
import router from '@/wherever/your/router/is/initialized';

export default {
  methods: {
    handleClose(imageId) {
      // Do your stuff
      router.push({ name: 'image', params: {'imageId': imageId}});
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: I need the anchor link as people might copy the permalink.

Comment: strugling with same thing, seems this is only way

Answer (score 4):

You must use the `.native` modifier on the `@click` event of `router-link`. The reason is quite simple - `router-link` is a Vue component but it does not emit a `click` event. Therefore you have to listen for the native `click` event coming from the browser.

https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/issues/800

```js
var router = new VueRouter({
routes:
[
{path: '/', component: {
template: '#first',
methods:
{
  showAlert(text)
  {
    window.alert(text);
  }
}
}},
{path: '/second', component: {
template: '#second',
methods:
{
  showAlert(text)
  {
    window.alert(text);
  }
}
}},
]
});
new Vue(
{
template: '#main',
router: router,
}).$mount('#app');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-router/dist/vue-router.js"></script>
<div id="app">test</div>
<template id="main">
<div>
<router-view></router-view>
</div>
</template>
<template id="first">
<router-link to="/second" @click.native="showAlert('second')">GOTO second</router-link>
</template>
<template id="second">
<router-link to="/" @click.native="showAlert('first')">GOTO first</router-link>
</template>
```

Comment: It actually does emit the  `click` event.  And as in the first answer, both `@click` and `@click.native` resulted in the same behaviour, so neither worked. Only the span trick worked.

Comment: `@click.native` works just fine, as you can see if you run the code snippet above.

Comment: vue3 removed .native, this will not compile

Comment: @JiroMatchonson Can you provide a link to the official documentation, where the removal of `.native` is documented?

Comment: I'm using vue-router 3.2.0 and this answer worked for me where `@click` did not.