# In Vue.js, why run a fetchData method after the BeforeRouteEnter Navigation Guard?

Tags: vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

So I've seen this example in code multiple times and I've tried to grasp what looks to me like duplicate fetch functions. I understand what the Navigation Guard does in that it pulls the data so it can be rendered before the page is displayed. But I don't understand why the `fetchData` method is called to do the same thing immediately after. Or maybe I'm just not understanding this code properly. I actually ran the code and commented out the `fetchData` method and did not see any difference.

```
<script>
  import db from './firebaseInit'
  export default {
    name: 'view-contact',
    data () {
      return {
        firstname: null,
        lastname: null,
        emailaddress: null,
        phonenumber: null
      }
    },
    beforeRouteEnter (to, from, next) {
      db.collection('contacts').where('slug', '==', to.params.person).get().then((querySnapshot) => {
        querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
          next(vm => {
            vm.firstname = doc.data().firstname
            vm.lastname = doc.data().lastname
            vm.emailaddress = doc.data().emailaddress
            vm.phonenumber = doc.data().phonenumber
          })
        })
      })
    },
    watch: {
      '$route': 'fetchData'
    },
    methods: {
      fetchData () {
        db.collection('contacts').where('slug', '==', this.$route.params.person).get().then((querySnapshot) => {
          querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
            console.log(doc.id, ' => ', doc.data())
            this.firstname = doc.data().firstname
            this.lastname = doc.data().lastname
            this.emailaddress = doc.data().emailaddress
            this.phonenumber = doc.data().phonenumber
          })
        })
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: pkc456, Thank You for fixing the format for me!

Comment: Ok, with some additional research I understand that running the watcher & fetchData is to react to parameter changes and it seems like standard protocol when working with parameters. I was able to find this related question on another post. [Best Practice for Reacting to Params Changes with Vue Router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40404787/best-practice-for-reacting-to-params-changes-with-vue-router)

Comment: However I still am a bit fuzzy to the exact explanation except for that it's standard protocol. Any additional explanation would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I got this from the Vue.js docs: -- "One thing to note when using routes with params is that when the user navigates from /user/foo to /user/bar, the same component instance will be reused. Since both routes render the same component, this is more efficient than destroying the old instance and then creating a new one. However, this also means that the lifecycle hooks of the component will not be called."  -- I guess conceptually I need to get grasp the SPA concept better when instead of physical pages it's components and routes.

Comment: You explained it to yourself in the comments. The guard loads the initially needed data and afterwards calls `next` so that the component gets rendered. But if you change the params of the route nothing would be updated because the guard is not called again (it's still the same component). Thats why you watch the params and reload the data on change.