# Vue: :key="$route.fullPath" performance issue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I was debugging an issue that has been in an application for a long time. After a while I figured out that `:key="$route.fullPath"` on `<router-vie>` was causing the issue because an anchor tag was added to the path. Long story short, after removing `:key="$route.fullPath"` I noticed a huge performance boost in the application. Pages render much faster, HTTP requests to the backend run faster, ... Altogether a nice surprise.

What causes this performance boost? I find little to no information about this.

Comment: I cannot reproduce that with an example application. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Sounds strange but interesting. Can you reproduce and show us?

Comment: I have been using that [since the end of 2016](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40404787/best-practice-for-reacting-to-params-changes-with-vue-router) in all of my apps and never had a problem with it.

Comment: I will try to reproduce this, I obviously cannot share the project. I will keep this updated.