# Vue. How to route on current page

Tags: vue.js

I have page '/users'.

```
export default {
  name: 'Users',
  created () {
    const queryParams = this.$route.query
    this[GET_USERS_FROM_SERVER](queryParams)
  },
  methods: {
    ...mapActions([GET_USERS_FROM_SERVER]),
    onBtnFilterClick () {
      this.$route.push('/users?minAge=20&name=alex&withPhoto=true')
    }
  }
}
```

When page started, it checks params and gets users from server. But it doesnt work and i think it is because router think that `'/users'` and `'/users?params'` is the same path.

If I add `this.$router.go()` after `this.$router.go()` it will reload current page and it works. But I want to do it in another way. How can I do this?

Comment: Might be related to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40404787/best-practice-for-reacting-to-params-changes-with-vue-router

Answer (score 0):

Don't reload the page if you do not have to.

`this.$route.query` can be just as reactive as your other data, so use this fact.

```
export default {
  name: 'Users',
  watch: {
    '$route.query': {
      immediate: true,
      deep: true,
      handler (queryParams) {
        this[GET_USERS_FROM_SERVER](queryParams)
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    ...mapActions([GET_USERS_FROM_SERVER]),
    onBtnFilterClick () {
      this.$route.push('/users?minAge=20&name=alex&withPhoto=true')
    }
  }
}
```

When you watch for changes on `$route.query`, you call `this[GET_USERS_FROM_SERVER]` whenever it changes. I suspect that this changes the data in your component. I've set the `immediate` flag to run it when the component is created. I've set the `deep` flag, because this is an object, and I am not entirely sure if the query object gets replaced with every route change, or just modified. The deep flag will make sure that it will always trigger the handler.