# VueJS router.push not updating data inside page

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I am using NuxtJS and I have a NavBar that goes to `/website?web=1` and `/website?web=2`.. When I go from `/website?web=1` to `/website?web=2` vice versa.. My `async fetch` is not running at all.

**website.vue**

```
async fetch({ store, error, route, params }) {
    let parameters;
    const pageLimit = store.state.websites.pageLimit;
    const offset = params.id ? (params.id - 1) * pageLimit : 0;
    const web = route.query.web;
    try {
      if (web === "1") {
        parameters = `?&is_global=true&offset=${offset}&limit=${pageLimit}`;
      } else if (web === "2") {
        parameters = `?&is_global=false&offset=${offset}&limit=${pageLimit}`;
      } else {
        parameters = `?co_id=${
          route.query.co_id ? route.query.co_id : ""
        }&ca_id=${
          route.query.ca_id ? route.query.ca_id : ""
        }&limit=${pageLimit}&offset=${offset}`;
      }
      await Promise.all([

        store.dispatch("websites/fetchWebsites", parameters)
      ]);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log("Error: " + e);
    }
  },
```

**NavBar.vue**

```
methods: {
    handleClick(tab, event) {
      switch (tab.label) {
        case "1":
          this.$router.push({ name: "index" });
          break;
        case "2":
          this.$router.push("/country");
          break;
        case "3":
          this.$router.push("/website?web=1");
          break;
        case "4":
          this.$router.push("/website?web=2");
          break;
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Best Practice for Reacting to Params Changes with Vue Router](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40404787/best-practice-for-reacting-to-params-changes-with-vue-router)

Comment: See also https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/dynamic-matching.html#reacting-to-params-changes

Answer (score 2):

### When using Nuxt's fetch(), you need an explicit watcher to listen for route changes.

For a Nuxt component which has `async fetch()`, if you want it to update when the route changes, then setup a standard watcher.

See docs: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/features/data-fetching#listening-to-query-string-changes

```
export default {

  watch: {
      '$route.query': '$fetch'   // This runs $fetch, defined below
  },

  async fetch() {
      // Runs on server load (SSR), or when called (see above)
  }

}
```

**For other context's (or before Nuxt 2.12):**

You could explore using `watchQuery`.

See docs: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/components-glossary/pages-watchquery/

```
export default {

  watchQuery(newQuery, oldQuery) {
    // Only execute component methods if the old query string contained `bar`
    // and the new query string contains `foo`
    return newQuery.foo && oldQuery.bar
  }

}
```

https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/components-glossary/pages-watchquery/

Comment: Nice! so, does it rerender the template or just update the updated data?

Comment: It rerenders. Good thing NuxtJS has its native way of dealing this.. Otherwise I will use watcher

Comment: Alternatively, you could use a regular `watch` as well; [see docs](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/features/data-fetching#listening-to-query-string-changes).

Answer (score 1):

### `async fetch` lifecycle is not *invoked* of `query` / `param` update

> Sometimes you just want to fetch data and pre-render it on the server
>   without using a store. `asyncData` is called every time before loading
>   the page component. It will be called server-side once (on the first
>   request to the Nuxt app) and client-side when navigating to further
>   routes [doc](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/async-data/).
>
> Also, a component does not *remount* on `query` / `param` update, so
>   lifecycles like `created` / `mounted` / `beforeCreate` etc are also not
>   *invoked* again. This helps in the application's performance as it avoids unnecessary *rendering* of the entire page where a few data changes would work.

*Make a common method*

```
methods: {
 fetchData ({ store, error, route, params }) {
  // your fetch logic here
  let parameters;
  const pageLimit = store.state.websites.pageLimit;
  // ...
 }
}
```

*Call the method in `async data`*

```
async fetch({ store, error, route, params }) {
 this.fetchData({ store, error, route, params })
}
```

*Call the method again on query change*

```
watch: {
  "$route.query.web": {
    handler () {
      this.fetchData({ store: this.$store, route: this.$route... });
    }
  },
```

*Alternative to watch*

```
beforeRouteUpdate (to, from, next) {
 if (from.name === to.name) { // Call fn only when: route hasn't changed instead just query / params for the route has changed
  this.fetchData({ store: this.$store, route: this.$route... })
 }
},
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I came up with a better answer

Comment: FYI, to be clear, `async fetch` and `async asyncData` are two different things; [see docs](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/features/data-fetching).